# Strange pytest with AWS CDK issue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pytest, aws-cdk

I have a big project on AWS CDK with python, and  this is the first time I encounter this issue, in resume:

- I added a second DNS CNAME domain to my stack.
- I run cdk diff, looks good.
- I deploy
- I check and looks deployed as expected, so far everything good.
- So then I am, crap I forgot to write a unites, so I go the piece with the current
  test for the preview route53 CNAME record, I added and copy it and changed the values.
  Problem: It keeps failing, after like 8 hours trying to change the way I do the test
  I decided to delete the second test for the second CNAME and do a simple test:

```
template.resource_count_is("AWS::Route53::RecordSet", 1)
```

This above works!
but this does not!

```
template.resource_count_is("AWS::Route53::RecordSet", 2)
```

I'm like what??? I go double check, do a `cdk synth` I see both!

```
cat my-stack.template.json | grep Route53
   "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
   "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
```

Furthermore, I have been like 4 hours looking online to see if there is anything similar or to see if is using a cache template etc., but remember this is deployed and working, also it shows to me on `cdk synth` etc... :(

- The original test works and is currently working, the second test is a copy/paste with the values for the second CNAME and diff method name...

```
def test_dns1():
    template = _my_template()

    template.has_resource_properties(
        'AWS::Route53::RecordSet',
        {
            'Name': 'x.x.net.',
            'Type': 'CNAME',
            'ResourceRecords': [f'{x}-{x}.{region}.elasticbeanstalk.com'],
            'TTL': '300',
        },
    )
```